Не работает merge запрос к ORACLE BD
При заполнении параметров подстановка productName идёт напрямую, без кавычек, to_char не работает
Мой код:
MERGE INTO STORE_PRODUCTS ps
USING (
    SELECT :storeId AS store_id,
           p.ID AS product_id,
           :productCount AS product_count
    FROM products p
    WHERE p.NAME = :productName
) src
ON (ps.storeid = src.store_id AND ps.productid = src.product_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET ps.COUNTPRODUCT = PS.COUNTPRODUCT + src.product_count
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (storeid, productid, COUNTPRODUCT)
    VALUES (src.store_id, src.product_id, src.product_count);

Вывод консоли:
MERGE INTO STORE_PRODUCTS ps
         USING (
             SELECT 1 AS store_id,
                    p.ID AS product_id,
                    10 AS product_count
             FROM products p
             WHERE p.NAME = CARS
         ) src
         ON (ps.storeid = src.store_id AND ps.productid = src.product_id)
         WHEN MATCHED THEN
             UPDATE SET ps.COUNTPRODUCT = PS.COUNTPRODUCT + src.product_count
         WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
             INSERT (storeid, productid, COUNTPRODUCT)
             VALUES (src.store_id, src.product_id, src.product_count)
[2024-09-03 23:21:29] [42000][904] ORA-00904: "CARS": недопустимый идентификатор
[2024-09-03 23:21:29] Position: 170

JAVA код выглядит так, при выполнении код зависает, ошибки не выдаёт
public void mergeProducts(int storeId, ProductEnum productEnum, int countProduct) {
        String sql = "MERGE INTO STORE_PRODUCTS ps\n" +
                "USING (\n" +
                "    SELECT ? AS store_id,\n" +
                "           p.ID AS product_id,\n" +
                "           ? AS product_count\n" +
                "    FROM products p\n" +
                "    WHERE p.NAME = ?\n" +
                ") src\n" +
                "ON (ps.storeid = src.store_id AND ps.productid = src.product_id)\n" +
                "WHEN MATCHED THEN\n" +
                "    UPDATE SET ps.COUNTPRODUCT = PS.COUNTPRODUCT + src.product_count\n" +
                "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN\n" +
                "    INSERT (storeid, productid, COUNTPRODUCT)\n" +
                "    VALUES (src.store_id, src.product_id, src.product_count)";
        try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setInt(1, storeId);
            statement.setInt(2, countProduct);
            statement.setString(3, productEnum.toString());
            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error merge " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


Нужны подробности. Как объявлены bind- переменные. Как вызывается данный блок, откуда

Если честно, не знаю что такое bind-переменные, блок будет вызываться из java кода, в него будут подставляться значения через setInt и setString

Ну так покажите java код. Вы похоже передаете productName не как строку. А bind переменные это в оракле переменные, начинающиеся с :. Их биндядт )

Добавил код, до этого выполнение sql запроса происходило из sql developer, я задавал данные для трёх своих переменных и оно выдавало ошибку, если же заменить :productName на 'CARS', всё работает без проблем

Какой странный JDBC драйвер, подставляет строку в текст запроса. Как он называется и какая у него версия?

В консольном выводе я не вижу "Error merge". Это точно вывод этого кода?


com.oracle.database.jdbc
ojdbc8
19.8.0.0

Это вывод этого кода, ошибка происходит во время подстановки значения из bind-переменной на место :productName, имя вводится без кавычек и потому воспринимается как идентификатор

Нужно, чтобы в запросе, который выполняете из java, переменная :productName была в кавычках.
Например:
"    WHERE p.NAME = '?'\n" +

В этом случае значение будет подставлено корректно.
